# How to refer to a Table in the LOT without having to put a caption below it?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

I was looking at a few examples on how to list a Table in the LOT without the need to have a \caption below the acutal table.
There was a nice example from Alan Munn

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{blank}{}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[hpb]
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{foo}
\captionsetup{textformat=empty,labelformat=blank}
\caption{A caption that doesn't appear under the figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but **even that one still gives me a "Table 1:" caption below the table**... at least without the text behind it but I want to get rid of that line completely as I have it in the table already. Any idea on what I did wrong?

Here´s my code:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{blank}{}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
\endgroup}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{Supplement}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth]{ 
\includegraphics[height=.9\textheight]{Table_A1_1.pdf}}
\captionsetup{textformat=empty,labelformat=blank}
\caption{Something for the LOT}
\label{TableA1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\medskip
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[hpb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline{1}A caption that doesn't appear under the figure}
\stepcounter{figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[hpb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A caption that appears under the figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same applies to tables. I can't compile your code with an outdated system though, so I can't test.